# Stetho SQL DataBase when Inspeecting with google chrom not working

Tags: java, android-studio, stetho

I was just using my chrome to look at my sql lite data base like normal i started add more code and then for some reason my Stetho stopped working and not just for my current project for all of my projects it wont load it keeps giving me a blanks screen.[Inspect Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlvls.png) https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlvls.png
I don't know why it stopped working as I didn't do anything to database, Any help would greatly be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay So for me I Just Installed Google Chrome Canary and inspected my devices on that browser and it worked not sure why though and not sure why this error occurred in the first place.